# Why can't my Perl program find Array::Utils?

Tags: arrays, perl, module, cpan

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);# it showing error
my @array1 = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 8, 14, 95, 19);
my @array2 = (3, 14, 6, 22, 88, 19, 100);
my@isect = intersect(@array1,@array2);
print @isect,$/;
```

The `use Array::Utils qw(:all);`# it showing error.`Can't locate Array/Utils.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at grep_exr.pl line 5.`.Why it showing this Error.whats the wrong in my code? or any other method we have to do my requirement.Please let us know.your answers will be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it says, it can't find the module. Chances are it's because you never installed it

```
cpan Array::Utils
```

Or you can just write your own solution

```
my %array1 = map { $_ => 1 } @array1;
my @intersect = grep { $array1{$_} } @array2;
```

Comment: ikegami,How to install this module?

Comment: I downloaded Array::Utils module from http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils/Utils.pm.please tel me how to install

Comment: `[Ram@localhost work]$ cpan Array::Utils
bash: cpan: command not found`

Comment: You have a broken Perl installation

Comment: @ ikegami  then how to install properly ?

Comment: I would use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to easily install a local copy rather than mess with your system installation.

Comment: how to install perlbrew?

Comment: I provided a link. Read.

Comment: oops, this link better: [App::perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew)

Comment: just a thought, if you don't want to install too many library from cpan, go for python., python supports set and can solve your problem in one line. set1.intersection(set2)

Comment: yopy,I'm using Perl script not python

Comment: @yopy, cause `set1.intersection(set2)` is so much simpler than `grep $array1{$_}, @array2`!?!

Comment: `[root@localhost Array-Utils-0.5]#  perlbrew init
bash: perlbrew: command not found`

Comment: Did you install it? Did you make the change to .bashrc to told you to do? Did you restart your shell to pick up those changes?

Comment: Probably don't want to do that as root! I mean, you can, but it kinda defies the purpose

Comment: The other option is to install the missing parts of Perl from your distro's package repository. The reason `cpan` is missing is probably cause your distro broke Perl into bits. Your distro might even have a package for Array::Utils

Comment: `[Ram@localhost ~]$ curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
102  1020  102  1020    0     0    469      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  2922`

Comment: `## Download the latest perlbrew
## Installing perlbrew
perlbrew is installed: ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew
perlbrew root (~/perl5/perlbrew) is initialized.
Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a
new shell, perlbrew should be up and fully functional from there:
    source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
Simply run `perlbrew` for usage details.
Happy brewing!
## Installing patchperl
## Done.
[Ram@localhost ~]$`

Comment: `[Ram@localhost ~]$ perlbrew init
bash: perlbrew: command not found
[Ram@localhost ~]$ ` here i'm getting error @ ikegami

Comment: Did you read what you posted? **Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a new shell**

Comment: `[root@localhost work]# ~/.bash_profile
bash: /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

What about this without using module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                                      

my @union = @intersection = @difference = ();
my %count = ();

my @array1 = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 8, 14, 95, 19);
my @array2 = (3, 14, 6, 22, 88, 19, 100);

foreach my $element (@array1, @array2) {
  $count{$element}++
 }

foreach my $element (keys %count) {
   push @union, $element;
   push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
}

foreach my $k ( keys %count ) {
  if ( $count{$k} > 1 ) {
    print "$k exist on both the arrays\n";
  }
}
```

Btw, if you want to install Array::util, download the tar file from : http://search.cpan.org/dist/Array-Utils/Utils.pm

Do the following steps as root.

```
1. Untar it.
2. Run 
   2.1 perl Makefile.PL
   2.2 make test
   2.3 make install
```

Comment: ,how to install Array::util module.please tell me.

Comment: wow, that's a long way of writing `my %array1 = map { $_ => 1 } @array1; my @intersect = grep $array1{$_}, @array2;`

Comment: Thank you @ikegami. I know that too.

Comment: @yopy,[Ram@localhost work]$ cpan Array::Utils bash: cpan: command not found

Comment: can you do `man cpan`, looks like cpan is not installed, actually cpan is a part standard lib in perl.

Comment: if you don't ve cpan, also still you can install by downloading the tar from the cpan site.

Comment: perl -MCPAN -e'install Array::Utils' also does the installation.

Comment: i did what you mentioned in your that gives resulit: http://collabedit.com/and4h, name is ram.its successfully installed or not?.please let us know

Comment: @hd1 your answer is showing result =:`Can't locate CPAN.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`